# USPS Rate API Standard Post get Expected Delivery Date

Tags: usps

I searched to see how i can get the expected delivery date for USPS Standard Post.

I have it when i use `<ShipDate...>` tag, for all other services i receive `<CommitmentDate>` tag, but for Standard post this tag is missing. Their documentation doesn't tell anything about how to get this date using Rate API. Is it possible, or i have to make another request to different API to get this date?
On their online calculator they return Expected Delivery Day for Standard post service, so there is a way to get it, but how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the "Domestic Mail Services Standards" API.

Specifically, you need to send a "StandardBRequest" web services request for the origin and destination zip codes, and will receive the number of in-transit days as a response.